# jQuery Mobile: Swiping works on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, swipe

recently I started checking my pages on my new mobile (Samsung Ace 3). One problem I encountered was that swiping pages works on my desktop computer but not on my mobile, e. g. on this page:
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/orchid/mediaelement/2013-03-25_Pleione_Ueli_Wackernagel_Pearl.php
Resizing the images and the video for responsive behaviour works fine, thus javascript seems to be activated. The buttons for paging are also working fine. Any ideas what's the problem and how I can fix it?
Best regards - Ulrich

Answer (score 0):

Update: In the meantime I noticed by alerting that the pageshow event didn't fire. Therefore I removed the code above and now it fires. My new test page:
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/orchid/mediaelement/2013-03-25_Pleione_Ueli_Wackernagel_Pearlpageinit.php
But although my alerting indicates that the paths were I register the swiping are executed, swiping doesn't work reliably.